# Keeping installed packages across dist upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Ever since ubuntu provides 'upgrade' installation path (since 10.04 if I'm not mistaken), I took it and hoping that my installed packaged will be kept intact or automatically upgraded. But apparently that's not what was happen.

All my installed apps are wiped out and I have to install everything from beginning. Easy for ubuntu or partner provided packages but quite a pain for 3rd party packages.

Was I missing a step during the installation procedure? Or is there another way to keep my installed packages across dist upgrades?

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC 3rd party PPAs are disabled during Upgrades and if their packages conflict with the new ones they will be removed.

Comment: How did you upgrade, exactly?

Comment: The download image > create bootable media > boot > choose upgrade way. Not the 'Update Manager' > 'Upgrade' way if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

*(comment to answer)*

IIRC 3rd party PPAs are disabled during Upgrades and if their packages conflict with the new ones they will be removed. – Uri Herrera Nov 13 '11 at 18:29